# Почему не чистится стек в программе?

Tags: c, ассемблер

Есть такой код:

```
int ten = 10;
int two = 2;

printf("%d minus %d = %d\n", ten, two, ten-two);
printf("%d minus %d = %d\n", ten);
```

На вывод выходит это:

> 10 minus 2 = 8
>   10 minus 2 = 8

Стало интересно почему так происходит. Первая же мысль была, что стек просто напросто не чиститься от использованных переменных. Прикрутил отладчик к процессу, оказалось, что так оно и есть. Но я не понимаю какой смысл программе хранить в стеке 3 совершенно лишние переменные(1 и 2 - это копии переменных, а 3 -  это разность 10-2), почему бы их просто не уничтожить чтобы они не занимали места? Ведь они уже не нужны, а место в стеке занимать продолжают.
P.S: компилилось на mingw последней версии на дефолтных настройках

Comment: Строго говоря, эти переменные не хранятся в стеке. Вершина стека уже сместилась, и они находятся за ее границей. Тратить время на очистку (обнуление?) никто не захочет (если не выставлены соответствующие настройки компиляиции), поэтому, если разработчик сам такое допустил - ССЗБ.

Comment: Вообще в большинстве случаев при входе в функцию компилятор вычитает из SP объем занимаемый всеми локальными переменными во всей функции. Не делать же ему это по N раз если внутри функции вдруг будет цикл. значения кладутся в заранее предопределенное место в стеке для вызовов. Когда функция завершается она делает leave или прибавляет к sp обратно фиксированное число, тем самым освобождая одной инструкцией весь использованный стек

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во-первых, у вас в программе явное неопределенное поведение в функции `printf` - обращение к несуществующим параметрам `vararg`. Строго говоря, на этом месте можно обсуждение закончить.

Во-вторых, все очистки должны произойти после фигурной скобки.

В-третьих, что вы понимаете под "очисткой стека"? Это же просто отмотка указателя стека, значения при этом так и останутся в памяти.

В-четвертых, где настройки и версия компилятора, с которым вы экспериментировали. На высоком уровне оптимизации компилятор вышвырнет все переменные долой.

В-пятых, где ассемблерный листинг с вашими комментариями?

Comment: 1) я знаю, что программа работает не правильно, но в этом то и суть. я же не спрашиваю "а почему моя программа выводит некорректные результаты". 2) да... про это я забыл. 3) под очисткой стека я понимаю удаление из него мусора. ведь зачем программе хранить 12 лишних байт если их можно просто убрать. 4) mingw последней версии на дефолтных настройках, но сейчас проверю на  VS с максимальной оптимизацией. 5) а показывать то особо и нечего

Comment: @WenSiL Что вы понимаете под "удаление мусора"? Программа их и не хранит, просто пока что ей НЕЧЕМ И НЕЗАЧЕМ их переписать...

Comment: Вы допустили в вашей программе нарушение стандарта C++. Код, не соответствующий стандарту обсуждать нет никакого смысла.

Что значит ваше "удаление мусора из стека?" формально, стек очистится - указатель отмотается на 2*sizeof(int)+ выравнивание, если оно было. Никто не будет тратить такты на обнуление переменных - смысла в этом нет.